# How to hide only Javascript in the inspect element

Tags: javascript

I have done a project and if any person view the inspect element he should be able to see only the html code but not the Javascript code  how can we do that can we do that or not

Comment: You can't. You can [minify your javascript code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) to make it harder to read, but that's about it

Comment: It's not possible. *All* of the code needed for the site is sent to the client. That's the nature of client-side code and webpages in particular.

Comment: You can't - if you need to hide an API key, you need to wrap it on the server side.

Comment: I have researched in google but i didnt understand what about javascript Obfuscator

Comment: Obfuscation is a bit like minifying, but is designed to make it even harder to read. The idea is that you give it your javascript (which you, as a developer, can easily read/modify/improve/fix) and the obfuscation creates javascript that still works in exactly the same way, but with changed variables/functions/layout that makes it very difficult for a human to read. However, as I say, it's just makes it more difficult, that's all

Comment: You can reverse obfuscation techniques.  It helps but is not useful against a competent attacker.

Comment: Not possible. You can try web assembly. Instead of hiding Javascript you can show something else which cannot be immediately made scene by any one.